# How to create a database form in InfoPath 2010 and publish

Tags: 2010, infopath

I generated a database form in InfoPath 2010 but I don’t know how to publish that form in SharePoint 2010

First I really don’t know if I created a correct database form in InfoPath 2010 because I published that form in SharePoint 2010 but when I open the list in SharePoint I get an error.

Do you have any comment, manual or link where I can get information about database form in InfoPath 2010 and how to publish in SharePoint

I want to create a form where the user is going to input some data and they are going to summit to table of SQL Server 2008 but it is not clear for me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> I generated a database form in InfoPath 2010 but I don’t know how to
>   publish that form in SharePoint 2010

- **Update: 
  It is impossiblу to generate a database from Infopath. The database should already be present if you connect to or interact with it from Infopath**

In Infopath Designer on ribbon File >  Publish > choose further quite self-explanatory choices presented by Publishing Wizard

If you created an Infopath form template from Database template in Infopath Designer 2010 then you might not need to publish it at all

> First I really don’t know if I created a correct database form in
>   InfoPath 2010 because I published that form in SharePoint 2010 but
>   when I open the list in SharePoint I get an error

If you created database form then it is already impossible to publish it to sharepoint list, only to a sharepoint form library or site content type.

Access to a database through generated Main data connection of such a form can be made only from Filler/client form but not from browser through IPFS (Infopath Form Services). In order to get to database from Infopath form in browser it is necessary to use web services or code or third-party tools.

> Do you have any comment, manual or link where I can get information
>   about database form in InfoPath 2010 and how to publish in SharePoint

I believe Infopath wizard steps (of Publishing Wizard, Data Connection Wizard, etc.) which you used for creation of Infopath database form have very detailed instructions which you should just carefully read and follow.

Also you might find helpful:

- [Patrick Halstead. InfoPath gaps in SharePoint and SQL](http://www.infopathdev.com/blogs/patrick/archive/2010/01/29/infopath-gaps-in-sharepoint-and-sql.aspx)

---

**Answer to comment:**

> after I do the connectionof my form by SharePoint server its possible
>   tu publish or use this form in sharePoint or definitely I have to use
>   Web Service

Please put one question per post. The discussions are discouraged on this board.

It is not Sharepoint Server that makes connection or even involved in your case.
And this all depends on your requirements that are quite blurred and fuzzy in your question.

As I understood you created an Infopath template having chosen **Database** template under **Advanced Form Templates** in Infopath Designer. This form is nothing more than Filler form with forced on creation receive/secondary/read-only data connection to a database (you could have created Filler form and then any other data connections and "advanced" additions).

You can publish any kind of form to Sharepoint (or anywhere else). But the filler form cannot be run in browser (through IPFS, Sharepoint Server's Infopath Form Service). When the user opens (creates, updates, edits)  XML forms of filler type/compatibility from sharepoint, they are opened in client/filler form only.

Client/filler forms use another protocol for connecting which does not have double hop authentication issues which have browser forms. If you would want to change this form to web browser form, then from browser this kind of form has to use web service to connect to a database.

Note that browser-enabled forms can be run **both** from browser (and this is available only in enterprise Sharepoint Server's IIPFS), on server, **and** Filler (on client machines), while filler forms can be run only from Filler (but not from browser).

Comment: Hello 

 First thanks for your support 

According with your answer if I create a database form with InfoPath 2010 I can publish or use this form in SharePoint.

Comment: You publish a XSN form template and "use" XML data form created on the basis of template in Sharepoint. They are different entities. Database form is created as filler form and it will be opened in client from sharepoint if published to a sharepoint form library. Though, it can be changed

Comment: Thanks for your answer and support only I have another question about udcx file (connection file) if I generate a connection file and after I do the connectionof my form  by SharePoint server its possible tu publish or use this form in sharePoint  or definitely I have to use Web Service Thanks

Comment: See my update in answer. Please avoid discussions and open the post for additional questions

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this tutorial. Found it quite useful in the past

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/vivekbritish/creating-browser-enabled-infopath-forms-for-sharepoint-library/

Comment: Huh? That article does not have even a hint to any relation with a database usage. Even more, it is straight impossible to use those Infopath forms to connect to an external database